# Way to use c callback register function in c++ (google test)

Tags: c++, callback, googletest

I have a c file to test it from google test. It has a callback function and its register function in it.
How can I register a callback for gtest? Here is the sample code:

```cpp
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

/////////////////////////////////////////
// I have this code in c file
/////////////////////////////////////////
void (*add)(int a, int b);

void RegisterAddCallback(void (*callback)(int a, int b))
{
    add = callback;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////

// I use this way currently
// static int s_value;
// static void add_static_callback(int a, int b)
// {
//     s_value = a + b;
// }

class CallbackTests : public ::testing::Test
{
public:
    int m_value;
    void SetUp() override
    {
        m_value = 0;
    }   

    static void add_static_callback(int a, int b)
    {
        // can't add m_value here, but I need it
        int value = a + b;
    }
};

TEST_F(CallbackTests, StaticCallback)
{
    RegisterAddCallback(add_static_callback);
    add(1, 2);
    EXPECT_EQ(m_value, 3);

}
```

This is the test result. I want to make m_value to 3 by using the fixture. But I am open any working way.

```
Expected equality of these values:
  m_value
    Which is: 0
  3
[  FAILED  ] CallbackTests.StaticCallback (0 ms)
```

Comment: Most callback systems have a way to set a *user-data* field, which is passed to the callback as an argument. Typically it's a pointer. It can be used to set the object to call the actual function on. The `static` function then only becomes a wrapper which takes the *user-data* pointer, casts it to the correct object-type, and calls the actual (non-static) member function.

Comment: The function would need to know which object to change. Normally you could pass along a reference to the class but that requires an API that can handle it, which your current ones does not. So you'd have to resort to real ugly work-arounds like a global `static CallbackTests& ct_this;` ... `ct_this = my_obj;` ... `ct_this.m_value = ...`. Not recommended at all, consider designing this in better ways.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I want to accept your answer if you make it into the "Answer".

Answer (score 1):

What is the point of a function that does something which is not reflected outside? you'll need to change the `add` pointer to function.

You have many options, all of which include adding a parameter to the static method, or return value:

1. add a reference to the result like:

```
//pointer to function
void (*add)(int&, int a, int b);
//in the class
static void add_static_callback(int& res, int a, int b)
{
  res = a+b;
}
//call with:
add(m_value, 1, 2);
```

2. add a return value.

Comment: It was abstraction of my problem. The actual function for "add" is a parser which has some internal states. Is there any way not to change c part of code?